# "Als" oder "wie"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, adjective, comparison

Ich weiß, dass dieser Satz richtig ist:

> Das Wetter in Afrika ist heißer als das Wetter in Deutschland.

Aber kann ich auch sagen:

> Das Wetter in Deutschland ist nicht so heiß als das Wetter in Afrika.

Mein deutscher Freund hat mir gesagt, dass es falsch klingt, aber ich möchte wissen, warum?

Comment: In Schwaben ganz klar: "Das Wetter in Afrika is heißer als wie in Deutschland"

Comment: Haha das habe ich auch irgendwie gehört!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Einfache Regel:

> Für die Gleichheit benutzt man **so + Adjektiv im Positiv + wie**,
>   für die Verschiedenheit **Adjektiv im Komparativ + als**.
>   *Negation wird ignoriert.*

*Positiv* ist die *Grundform* eines Adjektivs:
groß, klein, müde, leise, …
*Komparativ* oder *Vergleichsform* ist die erste Steigerung, gebildet mit -er am Ende:
größer, kleiner, müder, leiser, …

Für das Beispiel aus der Frage:

> Das Wetter in Deutschland ist (nicht) **so heiß wie** in Afrika.
>   aber:
>   Das Wetter in Deutschland ist (nicht) **heißer als** in Afrika.

---

Nebenbemerkung:
Manche Dialekte folgen eigenen Regeln, die nicht der allgemeinen deutschen Gramatik entsprechen, z.B. Schwäbisch:

> <del>Ich bin größer (als) wie du.</del>

Comment: Ich nutze öfter als als wie. Schwaben nutzen öfter wie wie als.

Comment: @userunknown Schwaben nutzen öfter wie als als als wär wie wie als.

Comment: @Em1: Das wollte ich sagen. :) Kommen wir nun zum 'als wo'. :)

Comment: Mein Sohn guckt gerade die alten Wickie-Folgen, und da kam "der hat doch drei mal so große Segel als wir" vor... ist vielleicht eine alte Formulierung, denn ich würde dau auch "wie" statt "als" verwenden.

Comment: @Robert: könnte eine eigene Frage sein ... ich würde jedenfalls einer solchen Frage ein +1 geben.