# Should it be ‘so bunt wie’ or ‘so bunt als’?

Tags: word-usage, difference, preposition, idiomaticity

I came across the following sentence the other day, and my wife who is a native German speaker from Austria insists it is correct. But by the rules I have been taught it is wrong.  Can someone explain why *wie* should be used here instead of *als?*

> Seine Hose ist nicht so bunt wie die Jacke.

The rules I am going by are: *wie* when comparing things that are the same, and *als* when different.  So my interpretation is that the two items are different in that one is not as colourful as the other.

Comment: Can you maybe state the rule by that you consider "als" to be the right word? This way, we might be able to point out why this rule doesn't apply here. Btw., the sentence is (appart from the fact that "Hose" should be written with a capital H) grammatically correct.

Comment: I’m voting to close as unclear. I agree with Dirk that we need the rules you have been taught to point out why they do not apply here. The general case may be of little use to you. Please [edit] them in. If the question is put on hold in the meantime, an edit will cause it to automatically enter a reopen queue.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26697/als-oder-wie

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/is-it-als-or-wie-or-both-that-is-translated-as/23023#23023

Comment: Die Regel ist eine Ad-hoc-Simplifikation, die keiner näheren Prüfung standhält. Ob wie oder als hängt davon ab, ob eine Steigerungsform verwendet wird. A ist dreimal so groß wie B = A ist um das doppelte größer als B. A ist so heiß/nicht so heißer wie B. A ist heißer/nicht heißer als B. A ist 500% so teuer wie B=A ist um 400% teurer als B.

Comment: The rule is correct, but you have to ignore negations, like in English too: »Tom is as tall **as** Walter, but **not** as tall **as** Lisa. Tom is taller **than** Lisa, but he is **not** taller **than** Walter.« This is wrong: »Tom is not as tall *than* Lisa.« This all in German: »Tom ist so groß **wie** Walter, aber **nicht** so groß **wie** Lisa. Tom ist größer **als** Lisa, aber er ist **nicht** größer **als** Walter.» Das ist falsch: »Tom ist nicht so groß *als* Lisa.«

Comment: Using "als" instead of "wie" sounds swiss-german ....

Answer (score 8):

> Seine Hose ist **nicht so** bunt **wie** die Jacke. *(no comparative)*
>
> Seine Hose ist **weniger** bunt **als** die Jacke. *(comparative)*
>
> Seine Hose ist **weniger** bunt **wie** die Jacke. *(comparative, dialect)*
>
> Seine Hose ist **weniger** bunt **als wie** die Jacke. *(comparative, dialect)*

The difference is whether you use a comparative or not. Non-comparatives require *wie*. For comparatives, *als* is Standard German but dialect may also allow *wie* and even *als wie*.

Comment: Please note that a significant portion of native German speakers get this frequently wrong.

Comment: `Weniger ... [als] wie` is just plain wrong. Never use it in educated circles, and never in writing.

Comment: @Polygnome Unless you want to quote Goethe.

Comment: Goethe hardly wrote modern German.

Comment: So far, so good. Please take in a small sentence about Austrian being wildly different from German, which would explain the original issue... ;)

Comment: Going by the book, this answer is certainly not wrong, but it misses the many variations in dialects and even in "standard German" if the speaker has a dialect background.

Comment: @Stephie - By default, we are discussing standard German here. There was no indication that the question was meant to be regarding (Austrian) dialect. By the way, Terry's wife gave him just the right advice for standard German.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann good luck explaining the difference between "größer als" and "größer wie" to my fellow Swabians. Even if they fully know the theory, they will likely slip up every now and then. (I never referred to Austrian German, btw. )

Comment: @Stephie. I am from Swabia, too, and I have no problem telling *als* from *wie*. The question is obviously not that much where you grew up, rather: are you used to using standard German? It depends, of course, also on your occupation, schooling, and social environment.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I could name a few high-ranking managers in the automotive industry with a generous six-digit salary and certainly good schooling and social background as living counter-example... And yes I am perfectly able to use the standard German form myself. It's just that with age comes the wisdom (at least that's what I hope it is) that there are more "rights" than I previously thought.

Answer (score 1):

So (adjective wie) is an equivalence. E.g. "So bunt wie."

For the comparative, you would normally use Adjective -er als. E.g. bunter als.

But here, you are establishing a comparative using a *negative* equivalence. That is, "*Nicht* so bunt wie."

In this example, you keep the 'equivalence" form (in its negative version) to make your comparison. That's why you use "wie" and not "als."

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb:

as/like = wie

than = als

Answer (score 0):

The rule is correct, your interpretation of it is wrong.

You can maybe think of it as setting up the comparing phrase first into a complete sentence and then adding *nicht* for the negation. Or you might say that the *nicht* simply has to be ignored when determining whether things are the same or not.

Therefore, since it would be:

> Seine Hose ist so bunt wie die Jacke.

It must also be:

> Seine Hose ist nicht so bunt wie die Jacke.

Only the addition of the negation adverb has changed in the sentences.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I can't speak to the German rules directly, but I can say that the sentences directly correlate to what they are in English.

His pants are not so colorful like the jacket. (The jacket is colorful, but the pants are not so.  Implied comparison, I guess, but not really.  Simply stating the colorfulness of each item.)
His pants are less colorful than the jacket. (Regardless of the actual state of color of either item, the pants are less than that of the jacket. Direct comparison.)
His pants are less colorful like the jacket.  (No direct comparison between the subjects, but both items are less colorful than some unmentioned item.)

Just my zwei Cent.

I agree with Janka, obviously.

Comment: Wouldn't "His pants are not so colorful like the jacket" be more naturally expressed as "His pants are not as colorful as the jacket?"

Comment: Yes I suppose it would.  My apologies.